# Add text to div from array and remove it after X seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am working with JQuery for the first time an trying to figure out a thing without any luck. What I am trying to do is:

1. Get value from array and print it to a div.
2. Wait X seconds and remove the text from the div.
3. Move over to the next value from array and repeat the process as long as there are values in the array.

I got the following code that displays all values from the array and after 3 seconds it removes everything which is not what I want:

Div looks like this:

```
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Script looks like this:

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

for(var i=0; i<cars.length; ++i){
    $("#loader").append(cars[i] +"<br/>");

    setTimeout(function() {
        $( "#loader" ).empty();
    }, 3000);
}
```

Comment: so you want to display the next value from the array after a given time ?
what you want also if you get to the last element ?

Comment: 7 answers posted and a total of zero do what OP is asking for.  (hint: you're all forgetting about step 2 on the last iteration of the loop)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your code to

```
 var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];
var i = 0;


   function paintCar(){
        $( "#loader" ).empty();
        if(i != cars.length) {
              if(i < cars.length) {
                   $("#loader").append(cars[i] +"<br/>");
              }
              setTimeout(function() {
                paintCar(); 
              }, 3000);
        }

        i++;
   }
   paintCar();
```

For reference - http://plnkr.co/edit/NPqDpXHPYoBCNOgDK5d6?p=preview

Comment: Hey! This is exactly what I need. Only issue is that the last value "BMW" isn't being displayed for X seconds, its not being displayed at all actually. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Well, for me it is getting displayed forever. What do you want to do with the last value i.e. BMW?

Answer (score 0):

Here i have a good  alternative which is using **setInterval** instead of **setTimeout** to **avoid** using **loops**

```
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

var i = 0;

var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if(i < cars.length){
        $( "#loader" ).text(cars[i]);
        i++;
    }else{
       // stop the timer 
       interval = null;
    }

},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

### setTimeout

Anything that you pack inside `setTimeout` will be executed after the given timeout. In your example

```
setTimeout(function () {
    $("#loader").empty();
}, 3000);
```

The setTimeout clears everything after 3 seconds. Instead you need to load each element after 3 seconds.

### $(document).ready()

I do not see a `$(document).ready()` in your question, I assume you either used it but did not mention it or that your script was included in the end of the document. When using jQuery you need to ensure that the page has rendered before you can use the selectors on DOM elements.

### Code Sample

Try this:

```js
var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

$(document).ready(function () {
    loadItem(0);
});

function loadItem(index) {
    if (index < cars.length)
    {
        $('#loader').html(cars[index]);
        setTimeout(function () {
            loadItem(index + 1);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you @MichaelParker, I made the change to limit the iterations :)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `setTimeout` altogether by combining jQuery's `delay()` and `queue()` methods:

```js
var cars = ['Saab', 'Volvo', 'BMW'];

$.each(cars, function(_, val) {  //for each car ...
  $('#loader')                   
    .delay(1000)                 //wait 1 second
    .queue(function(next) {      //add to queue
      $(this).html(val);         //output car
      next();                    //continue with the next queued item
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
<div id="loader"></div>

<script>
    var cars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

    function showCar(){
        if(cars.length != 0){
            document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = cars.splice(0, 1);
            setTimeout(showCar, 3000);
        }
    }

    showCar();
</script>
```